# Response could not be serialized, input data was nil or zero length

Tags: get, request, alamofire, bearer-token

If I made a request using postman it responds OK but if I try to use it in my app returns
this error:

**"Response could not be serialized, input data was nil or zero length."**

that's how I'm making my request on SwiftUI

```
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        .authorization(bearerToken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6Im5yb2NoYSIsImNvcnJlb0VsZWN0cm9uaWNvIjoibmVzdG9yLnJvY2hhQGZvcnRlaW5ub3ZhdGlvbi5teCIsInRpcG9Mb2dpbiI6IjIiLCJqdGkiOiJjOGIwZWQ1MC1hY2UxLTQ2MzItYjQxOS1mZjI0NWEzOTkyYWMiLCJleHAiOjE1ODg3MDAwNzN9.TQxA9c9TzqtDbFJSbnWMIK_vUshdVWG5kUnSN2c4Gk8"),
        .accept("application/json")
           ]


    AF.request("http://192.168.0.14:81/api/visitas/movil/dia-en-curso/usuario/2020/dia/=05%2F05%2F2020", headers:  headers).responseJSON{ response in
  switch(response.result){
        case .success(let response):
            print(response)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
  }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because it's the same that I put in Postman

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66497734/4170815

Answer (score 1):

By default Alamofire considers responses that return a 200 response code but no data to be improper and produces an error. Updating the server to return a 204 or 205 status will fix it correctly. Alternatively, you can create your own instance of `JSONResponseSerializer` with the appropriate expected empty response codes and use that to handle responses.

```swift
AF.request(...).response(responseSerializer: customSerializer) { response in

}
```

Comment: The problem is that is not reaching my server when I made my request, I mean, if I try with another endpoints works properly or if I use Postman to verify